# Accessing page with trailing slash returns HTML w/o CSS

Tags: php, css, parameters, query-string, querystringparameter

I'm implementing pagination for the first time ever right now, though I have run into an issue.

When I access the website with a parameter (i.e. `mydomain.com/?page=2`) which is separated by a forward slash, it returns the page without any styling.

Accessing the page without the forward slash (i.e. `mydomain.com?page=2`) returns the page with styling, as expected.

However, I have read that the proper way to implement and use parameters is with the forward slash...

**Why is it returning a page without styling?**

## HTML

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/m-index.css">
  ...
</head>
```

Answer (score -2):

The reason why, is the trailing slash means the client requests `index/css/m-index.css`, when you want `/css/m-index.css`

All you need to do to is put this in your head tags

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: thanks. i'll try that. despite that, i'm confused by your answer. the value of my `link href` attribute is structured like so: `css/m-index.css`. what you're saying is that it should be structured like this instead: `/css/m-index.css`?